# Refund for Sapica card outside of Hokkaido

Tags: public-transport, tickets, japan, refunds

I've got a Sapica card, and apparently it's only [useful in Sapporo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAPICA).

Is it possible to get a refund for Sapica cards outside of Hokkaido, such as in a nation-wide convenience store chain?

Comment: I would think a send in and get value send to your bank account might be an option, not as useful for people who are not resident.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. Japanese transportation IC cards in general can only be returned in person at an office of the organisation that sold them. Sapica is sold by the transportation bureau of Sapporo city, so it can only be returned there. ([Here](http://www.sapica.jp/procedure/other.html) is the official page in Japanese stating that, for those interested.)

Comment: @Willeke http://www.sapica.jp/procedure/other.html